# Gridview paging with JQuery without Ajaxcontrol kit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

How to update gridview asynchronously just like ajax update panel in JQuery.

I have a gridview with paging on and I want to use jQuery to update the gridview while paging, just like we did in Ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way, but from how I see it, if you are talking ASP.NET web forms, you could do:

- Create your own updatepanel control that uses JQuery or:
- Put the GridView in the user control and use this technique: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/117475/Load-ASP-Net-User-Control-Dynamically-Using-jQuery.aspx

You could have JQuery do the postback of the form asynchronously, but that really doesn't give you anything over the updatepanel.

HTH.